# Getting Select Options From Array

Tags: php, loops, select

My code contains a select box for selecting multiple options.

```
<select name="menu-item-visibility[<?php echo $item_id; ?>][]" id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="chzn-select" multiple="true"
    <option value="AF" <?php $val = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true ); if ( is_array( $val ) ) { if ( in_array( "AF", $val ) ) { echo "selected='selected'"; } else { echo ""; } } ?> >Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL" <?php $val = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true ); if ( is_array( $val ) ) { if ( in_array( "AL", $val ) ) { echo "selected='selected'"; } else { echo ""; } } ?> >Albania</option>
    ...
</select>
```

The problem is I'm writing the same code over and over and the select box alone makes up more than 50% of the lines of code. Seems kind of wasteful. I'm wondering if I can apply some abstraction by looping through an array of the countries stored in a separate file.

```
$countries = array (
'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
'AL' => 'Albania',
...
)
```

Any insight into how this might be accomplished in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try -

```
<select name="menu-item-visibility[<?php echo $item_id; ?>][]" id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="chzn-select" multiple="true"
<?php
$vals = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true );
foreach($countries as $key => $value) { // Loop through countries
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" 
    <?php echo (is_array( $vals ) && in_array( $key, $vals )) ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >
    <?php echo $value;?>
    </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Removed the extra curly brace after `'selected' : '';`. And changed `is_array( $val )` to `is_array( $vals )`. Works great other than that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do like this, Its different from your code

```
<?php
    $countries = ['de' => 'Germany','pl' => 'Poland','fr' => 'France'];
    echo "<select>";
    echo "<option value=''>Select Country</option>";
    $country = "pl";
    foreach ($countries as $code => $name) {
        echo '<option value="' . $code . '" ' . ($country == $code ? 'selected="selected"' : null) . '>' . $name . '</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```